# AmCharts for silverlight, problem with scroller

Tags: silverlight, scroll, amcharts

I'm developing a silverlight application with amChart's StockChart. I've met the following problem: if you add for example 50 points to the data source then scroller doesn't work, there is a gray part and a highlighted part on the scroller and you can't move hightlighted part. However if you add 500 points - scroller works perfectly. Also if I add 100 points then i'm unable to fully move the scroller to the left side. 
I've developed an application which illustrates this problem. Here is the solution for VS 2010 (Also a bin folder contains ready to see app) http://www.4shared.com/file/KNUqnak5/AmChartIssue.html

Comment: +1 for providing full sample project. Makes fixing problems so much easier :)

Comment: I have no problem dragging the scroller with only 50 points, however I notice the stock control does not track the mouse correctly and moves at a different rate. This causes very odd selections when I drag it too far to the right.